# ComboBox doesn't highlight when selected programmatically

Tags: vb.net, combobox

vb.net 2012

I have two comboboxes with a DropDownStyle of DropDownList. I am selecting one of the ComboBoxes when the form loads, cboMyBox.Select(). My problem is that when I select (or focus, or selectall) the combobox programmatically it doesn't show the dotted line highlight. When I tab between controls the dotted line highlight shows up just fine. I am filling the combobox with data before selecting it.

How can I get the dotted line highlight to show up when I select the control in the code?

**Combobox selected in code but no highlight**

[image: Combobox selected but no highlight]

**Tab to next control and highlight shows**

[image: Tab to next control and highlight shows]

**Ctrl+Tab back to initial combobox, hightlight shows**

[image: Ctrl+Tab back to initial combobox, hightlight shows]

Answer (score 0):

I have done some experiments and it seems that once you have tabbed to any control like a combo box or a text box and later use the `Select()` or `Focus()` method, the select box (dotted rectangle) appears in all the combo boxes; even if you didn't tab to all of them previously.

The trick is to tab to some controls with `SendKeys` when the form opens.

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
    Handles Form1.Shown

    ' Select the control preceding a combo box in the tab order.
    textBox1.Select()

    SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}")

    ' Select the fist control to be selected when form opens.
    btnFocus.Select()
End Sub
```

It works only if the TAB key is sent twice (don't ask me why, maybe a timing issue).

Comment: I tried using Sendkeys.SendWait("{Tab}") and also Sendkeys.send("{Tab}") but the cursor doesn't move from the initially selected field.

Comment: Me.ProcessTabKey(True) will move the cursor however if I select a different control and use the command twice then select my combobox or if I just tab to the combobox using me.processtabkey it still doesn't show the dotted line.